# Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int' (C#)

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an If Statement, which when button1 is clicked will be showed in label1, when textbox1 is 25 or above, "Customer can receive £5 off purchase" and will show when 50 or above, "Customer can receive £10 off purchase"

My Code is as followed:using System;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace If_Statement
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int  numbera = 25;
        int  numberb = 50;
        public Form1()
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        { 
            if (textBox1.Text <= numbera)
            {
                label1.Text = ("Customer can receive  £5 off purchase");
            }
            if (textBox1.Text <= numberb)
            {
                label1.Text = ("Customer can receive  £10 off purchase");
            }

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Wondering where I am going wrong and if I can have an explanation of why and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'll need to convert it to int first like so --> if(int.Parse(textBox1.Text) <= numbera) { ... }

Comment: Parse your input... A quick google search would have told you **exactly** what the problem is...

Comment: And if the first "if" statement is true then the second one will always be true too. You need "else if" instead of the second "if".

Comment: `if(int.Parse(textBox1.Text) <= numbera){ ... }` this works for me . `int.Parse(textBox1.Text)` Thanks @OusmaneD.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the value entered to a number before comparing it:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        var number = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        if (number <= numbera)
        {
            label1.Text = ("Customer can receive  £5 off purchase");
        }
        else if (number <= numberb)
        {
            label1.Text = ("Customer can receive  £10 off purchase");
        }
    }
```

You should notice that code will break whenever the user enters something like "abc", as that can't be parsed as number, so you'll need to work with a more safer way to validate the user input like [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx).